# Convert a byte stored as string into bits in Perl and modify it

Tags: perl, binary, hex

I am trying to perform the following using a Perl script:

- extract two characters from a hexadecimal number stored as a string --> This will give a byte written as string
- Convert this byte to binary (I must keep leading zeros if they exist)
- change specific bits in the binary
- convert back to hexadecimal
- replace into the original hexadecimal number

To do so, after a long research on the internet, I came up with the following lines:

```
# Initialize my variable: in my function, this is passed as input
$str = '5B CD 02 01 10';

# Extract the two characters to form a Byte
$OldByte_str = substr($str,0,2); 

# Convert to binary. Supposed to give '0101 1011'
$PDM_OldBits =  ( "Binary: %b\n", $PDM_OldByte );

# Replace two bits.Supposed to give '01**10** 1011'
substr($PDM_OldBit,2,2)= '10';

# Convert back to Bytes. Supposed to give'6B'
$NewByte_str= sprintf("0x%x", stringdecimal(arraystring($PDM_OldBits))); 

# Substitute back into the original Bytes string.
# Supposed to give: '**6B** CD 02 01 10'
substr($str,0,2)= $PDM_NewByte;
```

with:

```
sub stringdecimal {
    return unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . shift, -32)));
}

sub arraystring {
    my $string = join('', @_);
    return $string;
}
```

However, the conversion to binary is not taking place; thus i am also not able to check the rest of the code.

As a beginner to Perl, I am asking this question here - in case someone has some hints or solutions to my problem.

Comment: And these then https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node36.html ?

Comment: Do you need to replace bits for every value in the array - or just the first one?

Comment: @DavidCollins I need to replace only specific bits, this can be variable (from one bit to all bits) but i tried to simplify my example. This is why i prefer to do that using `substr`

Comment: @user2413548 this is not necessarily helpfull as I don't want to perform any logical bitwise operations. instead, I just want to specify Byte and Bit positions, as well as the new bits sequence to obtain the new Bytes sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strict` and `warnings` will always give you hints when mistyping something.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub stringdecimal {
    # return unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . shift, -32)));
    return oct("0b" . shift);
}

my $str = '5B CD 02 01 10';   #Initialize my variable:in my function, this is passed as input
my $OldByte_str = substr($str,0,2); #extract the two characters to form a Byte

my $PDM_OldBits =  sprintf( "%b", hex($OldByte_str) );#Convert to binary. Supposed to give '0101 1011'

substr($PDM_OldBits,1,2)= '10';  #Replace two bits.Supposed to give '01**10** 1011'

my $NewByte_str= sprintf("%X", stringdecimal($PDM_OldBits)); #Convert back to Bytes. Supposed to give'6B'

substr($str,0,2)= $NewByte_str; #Substitute back into the original Bytes string.Supposed to give: '**6B** CD 02 01 10'

print $str, "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost exactly what I was looking for. However, I want to keep leading zeros when I convert to binary or hexadecimal

Comment: `sprintf( "%08b", ..)` where 8 is total number of binary places.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution - using only `pack()` and `unpack()` and one call to `substr()` (no `sprintf()`). It will modify each value in the array. (If you don't want that just take out the `for()` loop and replace `$_` with `$bytes[0]`.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature('say');

my $str = '5B CD 02 01 10';

my ($orig, $bits, $hex);
my @bytes = split(/ /, $str);
for (@bytes) {
    $bits = unpack('B8', chr(hex($_)));
    $orig = $bits; # for 'debugging'
    substr($bits, 2, 2) = '10';
    say $orig . ' -> ' . $bits;
    $hex = unpack('H2', pack('B8', $bits));
    say $_ . ' -> ' . uc($hex);
}
```

Output ...

```
01011011 -> 01101011
5B -> 6b
11001101 -> 11101101
CD -> ed
00000010 -> 00100010
02 -> 22
00000001 -> 00100001
01 -> 21
00010000 -> 00100000
10 -> 20
```

Using `substr($str, 0, 2);` to extract the bytes of interest - aside from being unwieldy - is potentially unreliable. If there is inconsistent white spacing in the input, for example, then it could extract `'B '` instead of `'5B'` or `' C'` instead of `'CD'`. That's why I split the string in to bytes using `split()` instead.